# Combine a fixed number of mergeMapped observables - RxJS

Tags: rxjs, observable, rxjs5, rxjs6

I'm using RxJS v6, but this question applies to v5 as well.

When using `mergeMap`, my original array disappears and while I can do a number of operations in parallel, I no longer have a way of monitoring when all those observables I sent into `mergeMap` are complete.

## Example

```js
of([1, 2, 3, 4])
.pipe(
    mergeMap(values => values),
)
.subscribe(console.log)

// 1
// 2
// 3
// 4
```

I'd like to see:

```js
// [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

The only way I've come up with so far requires getting the length of the array, but I'm sure there's gotta be some operator I'm missing:

```js
of([1, 2, 3, 4])
.pipe(
    switchMap(values => (
        of(values)
        .pipe(
            mergeMap(value => value),
            bufferCount(values.length),
        )
    ))
)
.subscribe(console.log)
```

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for the `toArray` operator. Or, if the order is important, the `forkJoin` factory function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When using mergeMap, my original array disappears

The reason is that `mergeMap` accepts an `ObservableInput` as parameter of the function you pass in. A javascript `Array` is an `ObservableInput` and therefore works in `mergeMap` and `mergeMap` does its job, which is to *flatten* the `ObservableInput` (consider that `mergeMap` was previously called `flatMap`).

So, as @cartant says, if you want to get back to an array, you have to use `toArray` operator.
In other words

```
of([1, 2, 3, 4])
.pipe(
    mergeMap(value => { // do stuff with a value of an array}),
    toArray()
)
.subscribe(console.log)
```

is equivalent to

```
of([1, 2, 3, 4])
.pipe(
    map(values => values.map(value => { // do stuff with a value of an array})),
)
```

If your array though contains Observables and you want to eventually get the values they notify when all of them emit, than you have to use `forkJoin`. This is a simple example

```
of([1, 2, 3, 4].map(n => of(n)))
.pipe(
    switchMap(observablesOfValues => forkJoin(observablesOfValues))
)
.subscribe(console.log)
```

Comment: `toArray`, which I didn't know existed in RxJS v5+, solved it for me! It allowed me to execute a bunch of observables asynchronously and optionally wait for all of them to finish to do something else.